# jQuery resizable using scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to implement the jQuery resizable (DOM) element which is triggered by scrolling inside (hover over the element and then scroll) the element.

http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#default

Comment: Possibly. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Its completely possible.....just add those jquery library and ui library. and write code for initialization after your trigger event.
`$( "#id_of_element" ).resizable();`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, however implementation is a matter of creativity. Here is my quick solution, you should work a bit on it to fit your exact needs.

```
var resizing = false;
var lastScroll = 0;
$("#resizable").hover(function(){ resizing = true; }, function(){ resizing = false; })
.scroll(function(e){
   var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
   if(tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop) {
      // the user is scrolling down
      $(this).height("+=10"); // or whatever
   }
   lastScroll = currentScroll;
});
```